# Merging two nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For a few days I am struggling to find a solution for this problem.
I have this XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Einreichung>
    <EinreichZahlung>
  <EinreichZahlungen>
   <MemberFirstName>JOHN</MemberFirstName>
   <MemberLastName>DOE</MemberLastName>
   <MemberLogin>1</MemberLogin>
   <Store>0180</Store>
  </EinreichZahlungen>
    </EinreichZahlung>
 <EinreichZahlung>
  <EinreichZahlungen>
   <MemberFirstName>DAVID</MemberFirstName>
   <MemberLastName>GREEN</MemberLastName>
   <MemberLogin>2</MemberLogin>
   <Store>0181</Store>
  </EinreichZahlungen>
    </EinreichZahlung>
    <EinreichPerson>
  <PersonBelege>
   <Belege>
    <MemberFirstName>JANE</MemberFirstName>
    <MemberLastName>DOE</MemberLastName>
    <MemberLogin>1</MemberLogin>
    <Store>0180</Store>
   </Belege>
   <Belege>
    <MemberFirstName>JANE</MemberFirstName>
    <MemberLastName>DOE</MemberLastName>
    <MemberLogin>1</MemberLogin>
    <Store>0180</Store>
   </Belege>
  </PersonBelege>
    </EinreichPerson>
    <EinreichPerson>
  <PersonBelege>
   <Belege>
    <MemberFirstName>DAVID</MemberFirstName>
    <MemberLastName>GREEN</MemberLastName>
    <MemberLogin>2</MemberLogin>
    <Store>0181</Store>
   </Belege>
  </PersonBelege>
    </EinreichPerson>
</Einreichung>
```

I need to merge the two nodes into one with XSLT based on the **Store** value so that the final HTML looks like this:

```
<pre><b>
Zahlung 1080: JOHN DOE
Belege 1080: details...

Zahlung 1081: DAVID GREEN
Belege 1081: details...
</b></pre>
```

I am new to XSLT so I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While processing a node, you can find any node in the xml tree using xpath expression. To speed this up, it's better to create a key, with "match" attribute set to element tag you are looking for, and "use" attribute as the index.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="belege-by-store" match="Belege" use="Store" />

<xsl:template match="/Einreichung">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EinreichZahlung/EinreichZahlungen" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="EinreichZahlungen">
  <pre>
    <b>
      <xsl:value-of select="MemberFirstName" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('belege-by-store', Store)/MemberFirstName" />
     </b>
  </pre>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Defining a variable may help in legibility (used Belege[1] as you seem to have 2 Belege nodes for Store 180, although thq question asks for merging 2 nodes)

```
<xsl:template match="EinreichZahlungen"> 
 <xsl:variable name="belegeNodes">    
 <xsl:copy-of select="key('belege-by-store', Store)" />
 </xsl:variable>
   <pre>
   <b>  
   <xsl:value-of select="MemberFirstName" />
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>   
   <xsl:value-of select="MemberLastName" />
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>   
   <xsl:value-of select="$belegeNodes/Belege[1]/MemberFirstName" />     
   </b>  
   </pre>
</xsl:template>
```

Update:

You can process each Belege with something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('belege-by-store', Store)">
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="MemberFirstName" />
</td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or (with another template for Belege)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('belege-by-store', Store)">
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lesiak, it really helped your solution.

Comment: Can you also help me in one more think - the 2 values from Belege - I need them both to show in my HTML document ( I arranged them in a table). The problem is that I need the values to be separated in table on different rows.

Comment: I tried the mentioned update and I am getting this: ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :Error checking type of the expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(belegeNodes/result-tree), step("child", 14))'. I am using XSLT 1.0 , could this be a problem ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the case. There is a difference in xslt 1.0 and 2.0 in terms of handling temporary trees - (the xslt 1.0 type is Result Tree Fragment, see for example https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/04/10/xslt2.html). I changed the answer to use key directly, not using the variable